# I need to use grep -P regular expression to find and replace two columns in a bash script

Tags: regex, bash, grep

If I have a list such as:

```
5       chr1
5       chr1
5       chr2
3   chr5
```

How do I use grep -P to switch the position of column 1 and 2?

If I use this line:

```
grep -P "(\w+)\t(\w+)" test.txt
```

to capture the text, how would I then replace it?

Comment: `grep` doesn't _replace_ text; it can only _find_.

Answer (score 5):

Better (easier) to do that in awk:

```
awk '{a=$1; $1=$2; $2=a}1' OFS='\t' file
chr1    5
chr1    5
chr2    5
chr5    3
```

Even simpler is: (thanks to @BrenoZan)

```
awk '{print $2"\t"$1}' file
```

Comment: I prefer a simpler way: _awk '{print $2"\t"$1}' file_

Comment: @user3298384 if it worked well then consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You *could* do this

```
grep -oP "\w+" file | rev | paste - - | rev
```

but you wouldn't

Comment: is it some kind of sorcery? I had never seen anybody using _rev_, thanks for the new toy @glenn

Comment: Your comment made me look at that answer again: "surely I meant to use `tac`?". But, both work. That's why you shouldn't do that, I guess: unmaintainable.

Answer (score 0):

you can use awk like @anubhava mention (*I love awk*) it will work fine
, but if you want to change infile content, try sed...

```
 sed 's/\([^ ]\+\)\s*\(.*\)$/\2\t\1/' -i file
```

Comment: I'm surprised that would work, with the `-i` option following the sed program

Comment: from sed manual: _-i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX] edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)_ sed save lives ;)

Answer (score 0):

with pure shell.

```
while read -r a b X; do echo $b $a; done < test.txt
```